# Prompt the user for a string

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a script that prompts the user for a string containing numbers separated by spaces, and then alerts the minimum value, maximum value, and the sum.

Here is what I have so far:

```
var prompt = (“Enter a string containing numbers separated by spaces”);
```

Comment: What, specifically, is your question?

Comment: Careful with those curly quotes, you want to use regular quotes `""`. Writing code in a word processor is not a good idea, use a text editor.

Comment: how do i alert the code to get the min value, max value, and sum? should i use the split operation?

Answer (score 2):

```
var input = prompt('Enter a string containing numbers separated by spaces').split(' ');
var min = Math.min.apply(Math, input);
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, input);
var sum = 0;
for(var i=0; i<input.length; i++){ 
    var n = parseFloat(input[i], 10); // depending on expected input
    sum += n ? n : 0;  // add if number
}

alert('min: '+min+'\nmax: '+max+'\nsum: '+sum);
```

==> [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rjHqm/)

**Edit:**

---

If you are not sure that only valid input is given you have to check the array manually           instead of using `Math.min` and `Math.max`, wich could result in `NaN`

Answer (score 2):

```
// Some variables we'll be using​
var numbers = "", arr, min, max, sum = 0;

// Don't let them pass without valid input
while ( ! numbers.test(/^(\d+\s?)+$/) ) {
    numbers = prompt( "Enter some numbers, separated by spaces." );
}

// Determine min, max, and the sum
arr = numbers.split(" ");
​min = Math.min.apply(null, arr);
max = Math.max.apply(null, arr);

for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
    sum += (+arr[i]);
}

// Output results into console
console.log( min, max, sum );
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GUcgj/

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = prompt("Enter a string containing numbers separated by spaces");​
var ary = input.split(" ");
```

This would load the input into the array `ary`. However, you'd need to trim any white space and check for proper input before doing any further processing.